# UTF-8 encoding why prefix 10?

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, character

As far as I know UTF-8 is a variable-length encoding, i.e. a character
can be represented as 1 byte, 2 bytes, 3 bytes or 4 bytes.

For example the Unicode character U+00A9 = 10101001 is encoded in UTF-8 as

> **110**00010 **10**101001, i.e. 0xC2 0xA9

The prefix 110 in the first byte indicates that the character is stored with two bytes (because I count two ones until zero in the prefix 110).

The prefix in the following bytes starts with 10

A 4-byte UTF-8 encoding would look like

> **11110**xxx **10**xxxxxx **10**xxxxxx **10**xxxxxx

prefix 11110 (four ones and zero) indicates four bytes and so on.

Now my question:

**Why is the prefix 10 used in the following bytes?** What is the advantage of such a prefix? Without 10 prefix in the following bytes I could use 3*2=6 bits more if I write:

> **1111**0000 xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Historically there were many proposals to UTF-8's encoding. One of which uses no prefix in the following bytes and another named [FSS-UTF](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode1.1.0/appF.pdf) which [uses the prefix `1`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#FSS-UTF)

```
Number   First      Last       Byte 1   Byte 2   Byte 3   Byte 4   Byte 5
of bytes code point code point
1        U+0000     U+007F     0xxxxxxx                
2        U+0080     U+207F     10xxxxxx 1xxxxxxx            
3        U+2080     U+8207F    110xxxxx 1xxxxxxx 1xxxxxxx        
4        U+82080    U+208207F  1110xxxx 1xxxxxxx 1xxxxxxx 1xxxxxxx    
5        U+2082080  U+7FFFFFFF 11110xxx 1xxxxxxx 1xxxxxxx 1xxxxxxx 1xxxxxxx
```

However finally a new encoding using the prefix `10` was chosen

> A modification by Ken Thompson of the Plan 9 operating system group at Bell Labs made it somewhat less bit-efficient than the previous proposal but crucially allowed it to be self-synchronizing, letting a reader start anywhere and immediately detect byte sequence boundaries.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#History

The most obvious advantage of the new encoding is [self-synchronization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-synchronizing_code) as others mentioned. It allows the reader to find the character boundaries easily, so any dropped byte or an invalid byte (for example over choppy network connections or a corrupted file) can be skipped quickly without destroying the whole content, and the current/previous/next characters can also be found immediately given any byte index in the string. If the indexed byte starts with 10 then just a middle byte, just go back or forward to find the start of the surrounding characters; otherwise if it starts with 0 or 11 then it's the start of a byte sequence

That property is very important because in a badly designed encoding without self-synchronization like [Shift-JIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS) the reader has to maintain a table of character offsets, or it'll have to reparse the array from the beginning to edit a string. A lost or wrong byte also cause the whole content from that byte to the end to be unreadable. In [DOS/V for Japanese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS/V) (which uses Shift-JIS) probably due to the limited amount of memory the table wasn't used, hence every time you press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> the OS will need to reiterate from the start to know which character was deleted. There's no way to get the length of the previous character like in the case of UTF-8

The prefixed nature of UTF-8 also allows the **old C string search functions to work without any modification** because a search string's byte sequence can never appear in the middle of the another valid UTF-8 byte sequence. In Shift-JIS or other non-self-synchronized encoding you need a specialized search function because the a start byte can be a middle byte of another character

Some of the above advantages are also shared by UTF-16

> Since the ranges for the high surrogates (0xD800–0xDBFF), low surrogates (0xDC00–0xDFFF), and valid BMP characters (0x0000–0xD7FF, 0xE000–0xFFFF) are disjoint, it is not possible for a surrogate to match a BMP character, or for two adjacent code units to look like a legal surrogate pair. This simplifies searches a great deal. It also means that UTF-16 is self-synchronizing on 16-bit words: whether a code unit starts a character can be determined without examining earlier code units (i.e. the type of code unit can be determined by the ranges of values in which it falls). UTF-8 shares these advantages, but many earlier multi-byte encoding schemes (such as Shift JIS and other Asian multi-byte encodings) did not allow unambiguous searching and could only be synchronized by re-parsing from the start of the string (UTF-16 is not self-synchronizing if one byte is lost or if traversal starts at a random byte).
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Description

Answer (score 6):

All follow-up bytes of multi-byte characters start with binary 10 to indicate that they are follow-up bytes.

This allows re-synchronization if parts of a transmission are broken and/or missing. For example if the first byte of a multi-byte sequence is missing, you can still figure out where the next character starts.

If the follow-up bytes could take *any* values then there would be no way to distinguish the follow-up bytes from single-byte encoded characters.

Comment: Even without missing bytes, this is also good for seeking within a UTF-8 string. Given any random byte, you can look at its prefix and know instantly whether it is the 1st byte or a continuation byte of the encoded sequence, and in the latter case you can then seek backwards or forwards checking prefixes until you find a byte without the continuation prefix. So the prefixes of *every byte* need to be in a predictable pattern.  Which is exactly what UTF-8 defines

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure whether Ken Thompson has publicly stated his reasons, but there is a straightforward explanation.

UTF-8 was designed for backward-compatibility with ASCII. Therefore, all single-byte UTF-8 characters start with 0.

It could have been designed to be as compact as possible, that is, with 10xxxxxx as the prefix for a two-byte sequence and all eight bits available for the continuation byte.  However, the current format already supports more codepoints than UTF-16, and Unicode’s official policy is never to break backward-compatibility with UTF-16.

Therefore, it was considered more important to make sure that no valid UTF-8 sequence could be mistaken for either valid ASCII or a different UTF-8 character.  This would allow as many programs as possible to handle UTF-8 data, including search and replace functions.  If anyone needs text files to be more compact, they will compress them.

It was therefore a higher-priority design goal to make it as easy as possible to algorithmically detect UTF-8, so as many possible applications could transparently support it as possible.  Very few documents in any other encoding will happen to look like UTF-8 mojibake by accident (but see “Bush hid the facts.”)  However, this could not be allowed to slow down decoding too much.

Therefore, continuation bytes have a prefix distinct from those of initial bytes.  These are in the higher-order bits so that discriminating between them is simple on any processor.  The choice of prefix also falls into a simple logical sequence: A single leading 1 denotes a one-byte unit, two denote the start of a two-byte sequence, three the start of a three-byte sequence, or four the start of a four-byte sequence.  None indicate no continuation bytes at all.  If it should ever become necessary to extend UTF-8, it would be trivial to continue this pattern.

Comment: "Unicode will never need all the codepoints UTF-8 makes available now" is confusing. Can you please elaborate what does it even mean?

Comment: @EugeneD.Gubenkov “Unicode” is the subject of the sentence. “will never need” is the verb. “all the codepoints” is the direct object of the verb, and “that UTF-8 makes available now” is a descriptive clause modifying “codepoints.”

Comment: @EugeneD.Gubenkov The reason Unicode will never need all those codepoints is that it is already official policy that any codepoint in the UCS can be encoded in UTF-16.

Comment: And, therefore, that the universal character set will never be extended beyond the range of a UTF-16 surrogate pair.

Comment: I appreciate your sense of humor, but I would appreciate some authoritative references even more. 
Of course of the Unicode table can be encoded with UTF-16 variable length encoding (just as it could be with UTF-8 or UTF-32), I still do not understand what exactly do you mean...

Comment: @EugeneD.Gubenkov i mean that [the official Unicode FAQ](https://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) says that the reason U+10FFFF will always be the limit is to be able to keep using UTF-16. Other rncodings could hold a wider range, and UTF-16 is the most limited.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand your reference. Please correct me if I'm wrong. You're saying that if we ever need go _beyond_ existing Unicode range (up to 0x10FFFF, less than 2^21), then UTF-16 is not going to support it, and the encoding schema that UTF-32 uses will be able to support up to 2^32 code points; UTF-8 in turn can be extrapolated to support even more (however it won't be UTF-8 as we know it today, but an extension of the same idea).

Comment: @EugeneD.Gubenkov Correct. More precisely, the existing UTF-8 format could go up to 2^21, a six-byte extension of UTF-8 could go up to 2^31, and beyond that, we’d need to extend the 32-bit character type. But what we have now is what we can squeeze in without breaking backward compatibility with older software, including Windows.